# How to remove a lock from a table in a Synapse Dedicated Pool?

Tags: azure-synapse, table-locking, table-lock

There has been a lock on 2 different tables since last night. What is the query to remove a lock from a table in a Synapse Dedicated Pool?
[image]

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Run this query to find the session_id of any locks on your tables:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.dm_pdw_lock_waits
WHERE object_name in ('table_name')
```

In your screenshot, it is SID52295

To kill it, run:

```
KILL 'SID52295'
GO
```